# Responsive iframe video resizes as expected on laptop, but not on mobile

Tags: html, css

I want this iframe to display at a width of 640 pixels on a laptop screen, but expand to 100% width on mobile. This works fine on my Macbook, on both Chrome and Safari, i.e. when I resize the screen the video resizes just as I expect it to. When I look at it on my iPhone, however, the video is the size of a postage stamp. What gives?

```css
.videodrome {
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .videodrome {
        aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
        width: 640px;
    }
}

.Absolute-Center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe
  class="Absolute-Center videodrome"
  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fGOy0C-V_9I"
  frameborder="0"
  allowfullscreen
></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it should be inverse, (because of some sort of inheritance issue) like this:

```css
.videodrome {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  width: 640px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .videodrome {
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="Absolute-Center videodrome" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fGOy0C-V_9I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```